# EventListener not working with anchor tel:XXXXXXXXX

Tags: javascript, html

I have a tag with `href="tel:XXXXXXXXX"`, and I need catch the click event.

I have tested the following code on chrome: `$(document).on('click',console.log)`.  If i click on this tag browser it calls the application, but does not trigger a `click` event.

`$("a[href^='tel']").on('click', console.log);`

This is working, but I my have a problem with content load by ajax. My code has loaded a page and after some time application added content by ajax. When i use `$(document).on('click', ("a[href^='tel']", console.log)`, there is a problem.

Comment: Hey there! It's a bit hard to understand what you are asking, would you minding asking it again in clearer English?

Comment: I think he (or she) is looking for **preventDefault()**: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_event_preventdefault

Comment: I have `a` tag with href like "tel:XXXXXXXXX". I need catch `click` event, but browser not trigger this event when i click on this tag. All other tags work correctly. 

When i click, then browser directly call application but not trigger event in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a[href^='tel']").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();
    console.log(this);
    alert(this.getAttribute("href"));
})

//or if you want to delegate your function
$(document).on('click', "a[href^='tel']", function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();
    console.log(this);
    alert(this.getAttribute("href"));
});
```

This will bind an event listener to all click on `a` tags with a `href` attribute and prevent the click itself. After click, you'll be able to use your console to see which element was click and what `href` was used.

Comment: This working. But my have a problem with content load by ajax. My code have load on page and after some time application add content by ajax. When i use `$(document).on('click', ("a[href^='tel']", console.log)` is problem.

Comment: You're on the right path! You can use a `delegate eventlistener` like this:

`$(document).on('click', "a[href^='tel']", function(e){ console.log(e) } );`. I've edited my answer for your as well.

Comment: Thx, but

`$(document).on('click', "a[href^='tel']", function(e){ console.log(e) } );` and `$(document).on('click', "a[href^='tel']", console.log)` is a same code. 

This no solve my problem.

Comment: It's not the same code, because you cannot prevent your call from a console.log. You `have` to use an actual `callback function` which contains a `preventDefault` and/or `stopPropagation` call.

Comment: Ok, you have right. When i write own callback i can stop propagation, but i have problem because event i not trigger ;)

Comment: Are you using both `e.preventDefault();` and `e.stopPropagation();` ? Also, if you're using jQuery (which you are), you might want to add a `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` which cancels jQuery-events from dispatching/continuing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found resolve.
I use earlier event "mousedown" and change attr "href" to "only number" for disable action click.

Code:

```
const click2dial_Event = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let a = $(this), number;

    if (a.attr('href') !== '#') {
        number = a.attr('href');
        number = number.substr(4);

        a.attr('href', '#');
        a.attr('data-dial', number)
        a.addClass('click-to-dial');
    } else {
        number = a.attr('data-dial');
    }

    //...
};

$(document).on('mousedown', "a[href^='tel']", click2dial_Event);
$(document).on('mousedown', '.click-to-dial', click2dial_Event);
```

Comment: You can use multiple queryselectors/events by using:

`$(document).on('mousedown', "a[href^='tel'], .click-to-dial", function(event){ ... });`.

`Storing functions in constants` is considered `bad practise` because it makes it harder for you and anyone else to find the original code.

Comment: I know first tip but in my opinion this syntax is clearer than your propose. Tip 2 is ok, good to know that this is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

This would get the phone number from the `a` tag starting with a value of `tel` upon clicking it.

```
$("a[href^='tel']").on("click", function(e) {  
    var hrefText = this.getAttribute("href");
    var str = hrefText;
    var res = str.split(":");
    alert(res[1]);
});
```

Comment: Hello, while this may answer the question, please provide some context to explain how and why it works. :)

Answer (score 0):

### On Initial Load

I would first recommend that you wait for the initial [DOM to be ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) before binding any events to elements.

```
// DOM ready shorthand
$(function() {
  $("a[href^='tel']").on('click', function(e) {  
    // Do work here
  });
});
```

### AJAX Content

If you are adding additional elements after the initial load you will have to bind events to those new elements as well.

You could also do something like adding a data attribute to the elements that you've bound click events to and only add to ones that don't yet have that data attribute - but that's additional unnecessary work.

### Full Example Code

```
// DOM Ready Shorthand
$(function() {
  // Click Handler
  function clickEvent(e) {
    // Do work here
  }

  // Bind click event to initial tels
  $("a[href^='tel']").on('click', clickEvent);

  // Arbitrary AJAX request for demonstration (wherever yours may be)
  $.ajax('/newContent')
    .done(function(html) {
      // Adding our response HTML to the page within #someElement
      $('#someElement').append(html);
      // Bind click event to the new tel elements scoped to the returned html
      $("a[href^='tel']", html).on('click', clickEvent);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thx, this is cool tip `$("a[href^='tel']", html).on('click', clickEvent);`. In this project I can't use this, but i will use in the future.

Comment: You can also do something like `$(html).find('a[href^='tel']')` which I think is a more readable and clean syntax.